# MySQL Partitions: data not balanced in partitions

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I run MySQL 5.1.47 with partition plugin ACTIVE.

I create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prova` ( 
`NE` varchar(8) NOT NULL, 
`ASSERT` longtext NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=MyISAM 
PARTITION BY KEY(NE) 
PARTITIONS 4;
```

Then I insert 4 rows:

```
INSERT INTO prova values ('AAA','this assert is from AAA'); 
INSERT INTO prova values ('BBB','this assert is from BBB'); 
INSERT INTO prova values ('CCC','this assert is from CCC'); 
INSERT INTO prova values ('DDD','this assert is from DDD');
```

I expect to find 1 record in each partition but:

```
mysql> explain partitions select * from prova where NE='AAA'; 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+ 
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | prova | p2 | system | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | | 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec) 

mysql> explain partitions select * from prova where NE='BBB'; 
+---+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | prova | p1 | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec) 

mysql> explain partitions select * from prova where NE='CCC'; 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+ 
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | prova | p0 | system | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | | 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec) 

mysql> explain partitions select * from prova where NE='DDD'; 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | prova | p1 | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, my question is: 
what am I doing wrong? Why the 4 insert aren't splitted into the 4 partitions? 
Why BBB and DDD went in the same partition?

Thank you very much for your help! 
Evan)

Comment: I just discovered that if I use A,B,C,D instead of AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD partitioning works fine. Can you please suggest how to partition the table based on string and not single char? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-key.html partitioning by KEY is similar to partition by HASH except that the hashing function is now choosen internally by MySQL (and not by user as in HASH partition).

The manual is not clear in this, but the function should be either `MD5()`, `PASSWORD()` or a function based on the latter one. So it does not select partition based on the value of `NE`, but on a hash computed from it. Used hash functions have even distributions, so when you have many rows, they will be distributed evenly between the partitions.

So if you want to choose the function by which to partition, you should use partition by HASH. But what you were expecting? Or what are the possible values of `NE` column?